# How does SQS messages behaves while using aws lambda with sqs event source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

[image: Serverless for reserved concurrency and event queue]

Above is my serverless config for my lambda. We want only limited parallel lambda(10) running, since it has db operations, using this configuration we were expecting Lambda to only pick 10 messages(**reserved concurrency**) at a time and only 1 message in each request(**batchSize**)

However as soon as I publish bulk messages to lambda, there are many messages **InFlight**. I was expecting only **10 messages** to be **InFlight**.

[image]

Based on below monitoring it seems like lambda is getting invoked many times but gets throttled and the concurrent executions are always 10.

[image]

**Questions:** What is the concept behind this behavior? Also, are the throttled lambda instances waiting for others to finish? Does this impact other lambda's running under the same account? [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sqs) doesn't give much information regarding the functioning.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your function is not throwing errors (not throttling but other errors)?  Perhaps the CloudWatch metrics will provide some more useful ideas of errors, throttling, or other concerns.  The documentation seems ambiguous, but with a batch size of 1, the most obvious expectation would be only 5 in flight unless your queue has been very busy for a long time, because Lambda claims to poll SQS with 5 initial workers, but can scale that number up to 60 over time... but that would only be 600 concurrent, max (w/batch size 10), so perhaps Lambda is pre-fetching more than needed.

Comment: Yup, ran few tests, all of them are getting processed, however I am still not sure what's the reasoning behind this behavior?.